# AngularJS : prevent location change on back button or move cursor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

- Want to prevent from reload or move back to history urls
- stop back button from browser on particular component

Note : only for angularJS not Angular(2..12)

Answer (score 0):

Please import required directive in function definition "$rootScope"

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
  event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the navigation from happening
});
```

You can put above code in controller definition or can apply with watchers as well
Also instead of rootscope can be applied on scope only.

Ref : https://www.markcampbell.me/tutorial/2013/10/08/preventing-navigation-in-an-angularjs-project.html